# Using triggers in postgres can I have an insert accept a new column to only be replaced by the lookup id?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Lets say I have two tables (`states`, `postal_codes`) and the user can insert into the `postal_code` new postal codes and their state.

| state_id | state_code | state_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'FL' | 'Florida' |
| 2 | 'GA' | 'Georgia' |

| postal_code | state_id |
| --- | --- |
| '12345' | 1 |
| '54321' | 2 |

Is it possible using a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to allow the `INSERT INTO` command have a `state_code` and the function replaces it with the appropriate `state_id`?

Could I do something like the following:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_postal_code()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT s.state_id
    FROM states s
    WHERE s.state_code = NEW.state_code
    INTO NEW.state_id;
    RAISE NOTICE '%', NEW;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_postal_code_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON postal_codes
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION insert_postal_code();

INSERT INTO postal_codes (postal_code, state_code)
VALUES ('12345', 'FL');
```

Or do I just have to include the `SELECT` into the `INSERT` every time?

```sql
INSERT INTO postal_codes (postal_code, state_id)
SELECT '12345', s.state_id
FROM states s
WHERE s.state_code = 'FL';
```

Comment: Not possible and too complex as well: A simple select is good enough

Comment: Not that it matters but it should be `state_code = 'NY'`. It happens that 12345 is the actual postal (zip) code for Schenectady, NY. But you do need to be on guard for postal codes that are in 2 states - and they do exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` statement with `state_code` won't succeed as you're trying to insert into a field that doesn't exist in the the `postal_codes` table.

So, no, as is, what you're trying to do isn't going to work.

What I would do with this is ditch the `id` field on the states table, and use the `state_code` as the primary key.  Then use `state_code` as the foreign key in the `postal_codes` table.

This makes the data in the `postal_codes` table more human readable (but that's a side benefit).

The `INSERT` statement will work as written. No trigger needed.

If you're working in a large project, you might have a rule like "all tables must have a `bigserial` (or as Frank Heikens suggests, `Identity` would be better) id field which is used as PK and FK".  In which case you can't use this suggestion.

If you really wanted to, you could keep your existing structure, but add `state_code` to the `postal_codes` table.  Then the `INSERT` statement and `TRIGGER` would work.  **But it would a bad database design**. So don't do it.  It would be duplicating data - both state_code and state_id in the `postal_codes` table would be doing the same job of identifying a state.

Comment: Advise: Use an identity column instead of a bigserial.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it a bit more inefficient with having a `TEXT` instead of `INT` as the primary and foreign key? Thinking maybe `state_codes` could be an `ENUM` to have the best of both?